# CSS smooth transitions for text size

Tags: css, css-transitions

With an element that increases in size on hover (CSS), can I ensure the contained text within that element does not also increase in size?

Alternatively, can I ensure the transition is far smoother than what I see in Chrome (Version 88.0.4324.150) on Windows? The text looks blurred when it increases in size.

```css
.panel {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all .5s 0s ease;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.panel:focus, .panel:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
.panel-link {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
}
.panel-text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<li class="panel" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(21, 21, 21, 0), rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.7)), url('https://herodevelopment.com.au/allbathroomgear/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/bathroom.jpg')">
    <a href="http://herodevelopment.com.au/allbathroomgear/design-build/bathrooms/" title="Bathrooms" class="panel-link">
    <span class="panel-text">Bathrooms</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

just determine text size inside panel not the span, and change it based on the scale, in this example for text to remain in the same size, it must be 2/1.03=1.94rem.

for your second question the only way is use anti aliasing but it has no effect in scaling and transforming like this.

another better way to do this is use an image element inside the li, and just scale image, this way just the image will scale or zoom and the text does not change in size and therefore remain smooth and not blurry.

```css
.panel {

    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all .5s 0s ease;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.panel:not(span):focus, .panel:not(span):hover {
    transform: scale(1.03);
    font-size: 1.94rem;
}
.panel-link {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
}
.panel-text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}
```

```html
<li class="panel" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(21, 21, 21, 0), rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.7)), url('https://herodevelopment.com.au/allbathroomgear/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/bathroom.jpg')">
    <a href="http://herodevelopment.com.au/allbathroomgear/design-build/bathrooms/" title="Bathrooms" class="panel-link">
    <span class="panel-text">Bathrooms</span>
  </a>
</li>
```